# python-binance api invalid symbol only for certain pairs

Tags: python, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, binance

I am testing pairs from https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo
there seems to be no rhyme or reason to the symbols that work or don't work.

`print(Client.get_ticker(symbol='BTCUSDT'))`
works
`print(Client.get_ticker(symbol='LTCBTC'))`
works
`print(Client.get_ticker(symbol='ETHBTC'))`
works
`print(Client.get_ticker(symbol='NEOBTC'))`
`APIError(code=-1121): Invalid symbol`
`print(Client.get_ticker(symbol='MATICUSDT'))`
`APIError(code=-1121): Invalid symbol`
`print(Client.get_ticker(symbol='ADAUSDT'))`
`APIError(code=-1121): Invalid symbol`

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Tickers reflect currency pairs that market makers are prepared to offer doubles on. I suspect that there is not enough market depth in the crosses you want. That means, if you want to trade them, you have to do it via a third currency that is quoted against both. Which will naturally be more expensive.

Comment: but these are pairs that are on the api website themselves. why wouldn't they show up when you query them yourself? NEOBTC is huge. there's no way it lacks the market depth.

Comment: Your link has a single string with a length of 1.4MB?  Do you expect us to read it? Can you please provide __minimal reproducible example__ https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: I have the same problem with a php api, some symbols work while others don't work. Any sollution so far?